# Problema para probar mi ruteador con POSTMAN

Tags: postman

He desarrollado un ruteador en Java con Express, tiene el formato `api/carts/:cid/products/`.

La idea es que cuando el parámetro `cid` esta vacío, el ruteador genere un carrito nuevo.

Cuando lo quiero probar con POSTMAN, no logro enviar un parámetro cid vacío, cuando lo dejo vacío en el valor de POSTMAN me envía ":cid" en lugar del campo vacío y no entiendo porque.

¿Cómo hago para enviar un campo vacío?

Comment: Con vacío te referís a esto?`api/carts//products/`. Esto no está bien, debería ser la ruta `api/carts/`, y la manejas como otra ruta, idealmente usando otro controlador.

Comment: En realidad pongo en la pestaña de params de POSTMAN un valor vacio para el parametro cid

Comment: Lo que te está diciendo @eventHandler es que no podes enviar `api/carts//products/`, no es un endpoint válido que puedas manejar. De última probá usando literalmente esto `api/carts//products/`. En postman seguro estás usando la variable de ruta `:cid`, pero cuando no le das un valor, postman envía ese string `:cid` directamente.